# Unity3D Line Renderer Circle

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, line, geometry, gameobject

i want to draw a circle around my gameobject by using the LineRenderer feature.
After searching through the internet i found a code which draws a ellipse around my gameobject which works perfectly fine.

But from now on i cant figure out how to make the ellipse to a circle.

here is the code:

```
public int segments;
public float xradius;
public float yradius;
LineRenderer line;

void Start ()
{
    line = gameObject.GetComponent<LineRenderer>();

    line.SetVertexCount (segments + 1);
    line.useWorldSpace = false;
    CreatePoints ();
}


void CreatePoints ()
{
    float x;
    float y;
    float z = 0f;

    float angle = 20f;

    for (int i = 0; i < (segments + 1); i++)
    {
        x = Mathf.Sin (Mathf.Deg2Rad * angle) * xradius;
        y = Mathf.Cos (Mathf.Deg2Rad * angle) * yradius;

        line.SetPosition (i,new Vector3(x,y,z) );

        angle += (360f / segments);
    }
}
```

Comment: Make xradius and yradius equal and you should get a circle.

Comment: no when i equal the xradius and yradius to 3 i get an ellipse. when i take xradius to 2.5 and yradius to 3 i get a cricle strangly

Comment: What display are you using and at what resolution? Does this look like an ellipse too? [Link](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a0/Circle_-_black_simple.svg/2000px-Circle_-_black_simple.svg.png). If that circle looks like an ellipse too then it's all due to the aspect ratio of your display being incorrect.